# Issue populating assignment_group in servicenow via REST API

Tags: rest, servicenow

I am trying to create Servicenow incident ticket using REST API. Here is the link and body:
`https://<mydomain>.service-now.com/api/now/table/incident` and body:

```
{
"short_description":"testing short description",
"assignment_group":"Software",
"urgency":"Medium",
"impact": "Low",
"caller_id":"John Doe",
"description":"testing description"
}
```

Incident ticket is getting created with all fields populated as requested except assignment_group and description fields. I know these are reference fields. I tried all combination but information is not getting populated for these two fields. Any one has any suggestions? I tried for assignment_group the sys_id value also like `"assignment_group":"4ikilo9f1bb43740ddfa315bcd4kmj89"` and  `"assignment_group":{"sys_id":"4ikilo9f1bb43740ddfa315bcd4kmj89"}` etc.

Comment: Is it possible you have a business rule unsetting assignment group on insert or update?

Comment: Thank you Jace for your comment. No, there is no business rule that is unsetting. I can go and create a ticket and it would create with assigned group but not through API.

Comment: Do you perhaps have write ACLs on those fields which might be preventing your REST API user from writing to them?

Comment: ```"assignment_group":"4ikilo9f1bb43740ddfa315bcd4kmj89"``` should work.  Try doing this on a PDI.

Comment: Jace, i tried as you suggested. Same result. Ticket got created but with no assigned group info. @blendenzo: Can service now has ACL at field level? Like I have mentioned, I was able to create ticket using API but not these two fields. Not sure if Servicenow can restrict update access at field level? If so, why do they do that way? I will double check with my security group on that.

Comment: @MarkW Yes, ServiceNow can have ACLs at the field level. This allows you to protect certain fields from being altered by users, such as the State field on a workflow driven task. Some companies use this functionality to prevent general users from writing to a certain field (such as Assignment group), but allow a special class of users to write to it (members of the Service Desk, for example). If you can write to the record, but cannot write to those two specific fields, I would immediately suspect either ACLs at the field level or a business rule running on insert/update as Jace suggested.

Answer (score 0):

pass the id of the assignment group within the API call than directly giving the name of the group, this worked for me :)